# ti-nspire defining variables

Tags: calculator, ti-nspire

I want to define a program/function which defines a function itself and the 1., 2. and 3. derivative of it as global variables.
The name of the function should be variable.

Smt like:

```
Define LibPub der(a,b)=
Prgm
a(x):=b
a1(x):=d/dx (a(x))
a2(x):=d/dx (a1(x))
a3(x):=d/dx (a2(x))
```

with a being the name of the function and b being the function.

That doesn’t work because variable a cant be the name of the function. Executing this just safes a1, a2, a3

Comment: Like you said, you can't do this on TI Nspire. Just take the 3rd derivative as normal.

Comment: It's just impossible. As cool as those calculators may be, they have some hard limits, and there is pretty much no way to overcome them (for example, you cant have tables of 3 or more dimensions)